# JQuery on Knockout binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a table with two coloumns as below.

ISSUE: when I try the Jquery blur event on the text box it works on first row but when I add new rows(push new rows to observable array). The blur event does not have any effect on the new rows.

I am using Knockout.js

**JQUERY**

```
jQuery("#2CrpAcrs").blur(function () {
    var numb = $("#2CrpAcrs").val();
    numb = Math.round(numb * 100) / 100
    $("#2CrpAcrs").val(numb);
})
```

**HTML**

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach:Sec2">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <button class="btn btn-xs btn btn-danger" type="button" data-bind="click: $root.Sec2_RemoveRow">Remove</button>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select class="form-control" data-bind="options: CrpType, value: CrpType,optionsValue:'value', optionsText:'crop'"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input id="2CrpAcrs" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: NumAcres">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: See my edit far below. I suggest rethinking your code

The way that you're intended to do this kind of thing with Knockout is with custom binding handlers: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

I think you would do something like this:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.yourBindingName = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called when the binding is first applied to an element
        // Set up any initial state, event handlers, etc. here
        $(element).blur(function () {
            var numb = $(this).val();
            numb = Math.round(numb * 100) / 100
            $(this).val(numb);
         });
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        // This will be called once when the binding is first applied to an element,
        // and again whenever any observables/computeds that are accessed change
        // Update the DOM element based on the supplied values here.
    }
};
```

Then in your element you can do something like this:

```
<input id="2CrpAcrs" class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="value: NumAcres, yourBindingName: {}">
```

Also, your current code results in multiple elements with same ID, which is invalid. Consider using a class instead of ID for `2CrpAcrs`. This might be part of your current problem.

EDIT:

Why are you using jQuery at all? Why not just subscribe to your values directly? This is what knockout was made to do. You can subscribe to whatever you data-bind to your input element and do any custom processing of the value that you want there.

Comment: can you please point me to soem link I am confused about using class instead of ID since I alreay have a class for that element

Comment: You can have multiple classes on each element. If you do what I suggested with the custom binding handler, you don't need an ID at all. So just get rid of it. You can't have multiple elements with the same ID, it's not valid.

Answer (score 1):

`.blur` only binds to existing rows.  Use event delegation.

```
jQuery(document).on("blur", "#2CrpAcrs", function () {
```

By the way, IDs have to be unique so you should not use `#2CrpAcrs` and instead use a class.  It would also be better to use a more specific selector than `document` such as a class or ID on the table that you are adding rows to.

Comment: so if I add say id="2CrpAcrsTable" to this table and run the function as jQuery("#2CrpAcrsTable").on("blur", "#2CrpAcrs", function () {}

Comment: how do i get unique Ids for each new row added from knockout array

Comment: @sss111 you don't need IDs for the rows.  Use a class (`.2CrpAcrs` or something).  Within the `blur` method, refer to the current blurred input as `$(this)`

Comment: I am bit confused i am already having a class for the element and can you please redo your code so tat I know where do I use the current blurred element

Comment: Look at what I did in my code. I don't use any ID's in it. You could do the same thing without the bindingHandler I suggested by just using `jQuery(document).on("blur", "#2CrpAcrs", function () {` as @ExplosionPills suggests